# Mysql SQL query DATEDIFF failed in H2 where mode was MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, testing, h2

***Background:*** In one of my projects I am doing [component testing](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ComponentTest.html) on Spring Batch using JUnit. Here application DB is MYSQL. In Junit test execution I let the data-source switch between

- MYSQL and
- H2(jdbc:h2:mem:MYTESTDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL)

based on configuration. 
Use MYSQL as the data source for debugging purpose and H2 to run the test in isolation in build servers.

Everything works fine until in application logic I had to use a query with DATEDIFF.

***Issue:*** Query fails with

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement

***Reason:*** Even through [H2 run on MySQL mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) it uses H2 Functions and those functions are different

```
MYSQL DATEDIFF definition is DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
 e.g. SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31') 
      ==> 1

H2 DATEDIFF definision is DATEDIFF(unitstring, expr1, expr2)
 unitstring =  { YEAR | YY | MONTH | MM | WEEK | DAY | DD | DAY_OF_YEAR
 | DOY | HOUR | HH | MINUTE | MI | SECOND | SS | MILLISECOND | MS }
 e.g. SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31') 
      ==> 1
```

***Solutions tried and failed:*** I tried to write a custom function

```
 package com.asela.util;                                                                                                                                

 import java.lang.reflect.Field;                                                                                                                                                         
 import java.sql.Date;                                                                                                                                                                   
 import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;                                                                                                                                                   
 import java.util.Map;                                                                                                                                                                   
 import java.util.Objects;                                                                                                                                                               

 import org.h2.expression.Function;                                                                                                                                                      

 public class H2Function {                                                                                                                                                               
    public static long dateDifference(Date date1, Date date2) {                                                                                                                          
        Objects.nonNull(date1);                                                                                                                                                          
        Objects.nonNull(date2);                                                                                                                                                          
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1.toLocalDate(), date2.toLocalDate());                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                    
 }
```

And set it with H2

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS DATEDIFF;
CREATE ALIAS DATEDIFF FOR "com.asela.util.H2Function.dateDifference";
```

Above was not able to replace existing DATEDIFF still fails with

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function alias "DATEDIFF" already exists; SQL statement:

*Any other approach I can try to make this work?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a workaround with ***Reflection*** for the problem. Access H2 Functions map and remove DATEDIFF from there. Then add the replacement function.

```
package com.asela.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.h2.expression.Function;

public class H2Function {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static int removeDateDifference() {
        try {
              Field field = Function.class.getDeclaredField("FUNCTIONS");
              field.setAccessible(true);
              ((Map)field.get(null)).remove("DATEDIFF");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to remove date-difference");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static long dateDifference(Date date1, Date date2) {
        Objects.nonNull(date1);
        Objects.nonNull(date2);
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1.toLocalDate(), date2.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

Then in schema

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS REMOVE_DATE_DIFF FOR "com.asela.util.H2Function.removeDateDifference";
CALL REMOVE_DATE_DIFF();
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS DATEDIFF;
CREATE ALIAS DATEDIFF FOR "com.asela.util.H2Function.dateDifference";
```

Comment: for new h2 version (for me 1.4.200) `Function.class.getDeclaredField("FUNCTIONS");` should replace to `Function.class.getDeclaredField("FUNCTIONS_BY_NAME");`

Comment: Great answer and a follow up ^
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

asela38's answer works for me.
But some things about h2 package should change in my environment(springboot).

Very thanks to asela38 and Leo Lin :)

1. remove runtime scope from pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope> <-- remove
        </dependency>
```

2. h2 package directory changed

```
import org.h2.expression.function.Function; <--- change

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class H2Function {
    public static Long dateDiff(Date date1, Date date2) {
        if (Objects.isNull(date1) || Objects.isNull(date2)) {
            return null;
        }
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1.toLocalDate(), date2.toLocalDate());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static int removeDateDiff() {
        try {
            Field field = Function.class.getDeclaredField("FUNCTIONS_BY_NAME");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            ((Map)field.get(null)).remove("DATEDIFF");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to remove DATEDIFF");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the DATEDIFF issue by adding application-test.properties
here we are using MySQL DDL and dialect to override H2 default configs.
now we are using H2 in-memory DB with MySQL DDL Compatibility when creating SQL statements.
also in the classpath we can add schema.sql to initialize the H2 Database with sample data to be used in testing.

```
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:online_crm;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

> in the test class we then can use our profile 'test'

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.atech.crm.boostrap"})
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```